# Controlling the size of Histogram in PlotLegends -> Histogram

Tags: plotting, legending, visualization, histograms

I stumbled across this in the Mathematica documentation and thought it was pretty nifty except that the Histogram that appears as the plot legend is too small so the numbers on the histogram overwrite each other. How do you control the size of the histogram and it's annotation? I tried using LegendSize->2 and LegendSize->{2,2} but these failed. I also tried Needs["PlotLegends`"] to no avail.

```
counties = EntityValue[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {_,"Texas" | "NewMexico" | "Arizona" | "Nevada" | "California", "UnitedStates"}], "Entities"];
vals = EntityValue[counties, "PerCapitaIncome"];
pci = GeoRegionValuePlot[Thread[counties -> vals], PlotLegends -> Histogram]
```

Comment: The above code fails for me on V13.0.  Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to the Comment by @JEP, an  alternative is to extract the two graphics and the caption from the original quantity, `pci`, in the Question

```
p1 = pci[[1]]
p2 = pci[[2, 1, 1, 1]]
caption = pci[[2, 1, 1, 2]]
```

and then combine them as desired.  For instance,

```
Grid[{{Show[p1, ImageSize -> 360], Show[p2, ImageSize -> 250]}, {SpanFromAbove, caption}}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 7):

Rather than making the `Histogram` larger, I suggest you measure `vals` in terms of `$1000`.  Replace your last line by

```
pci = GeoRegionValuePlot[Thread[counties -> Quantity[QuantityMagnitude[vals/1000], 
     IndependentUnit["$K per year"]]], PlotLegends -> Histogram]
```

Dividing `vals` by `1000` expresses quantities in units of `$1000`.  `IndependentUnit["$K per year"]` provides the label on the `Histogram` axis.

[image: Histogram Legend]

Comment: This is a good work-around for the specific example at hand but my question was really one of principle. How do you control the size of the histogram?

Comment: @JEP, one approach is the method shown in my second answer.  There probably are others.

Answer (score 3):

You can interactively resize the histogram `Graphics` with the drag handles:

[image]

Or programmatically, using the part spec as in bbgodfrey's second answer:

```
MapAt[Show[#, ImageSize -> 350] &, pci, {2, 1, 1, 1}]
```